# Hide a link during users.new

Tags: ember.js

I have a `users` template which is a table of users. Under that table is a link to create a new user. For better UX I'd like to disable it by using `class="disabled"` or hide that link during the create of a new user. What is the best way to do that?

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='span7'>
      <table class='table table-striped'>
        <tbody>
          {{#each model itemController="user"}}
            <tr {{bindAttr class="isDirty:warning"}}>
              <td>{{lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <p>
        {{#linkTo 'users.new' classNames="btn btn-small"}}Create a new user{{/linkTo}}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class='span5'>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users/new">
  <p><strong>Last name</strong><br>{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding=lastName}}</p>

  <p>
  {{#if isDirty}}
    <button {{action 'save' this}} class="btn btn-small">Save</button>
  {{else}}
    <button class="btn btn-small disabled">Save</button>
  {{/if}}
  </p>
</script>
```

**app.js**

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'users' });
  }
});

App.UsersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  save: function(model) {
    model.get('transaction').commit();
    App.Router.router.transitionTo('users.index')
  }  
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one possible solution would be to add a property in the usersController, something like 'isCreating', which you can set to true in the activate hook of the UsersNewRoute, and reset to false in the deactivate. This would be something like:

```
App.UsersNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  activate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('isCreating', true);
  },

  deactivate: function() {
    this.controllerFor('users').set('isCreating', false);
  },

  model: function() {
    return App.User.createRecord();
  },

  renderTemplate: function() {
    this.render({ into: 'users' });
  }
});
```

Obviously you will use this property in the template and bind the class to hide the button.

Comment: How can I use a `isNew` check in the `users` template when the model is defined in `users.new`?

Comment: Thank you! I hoped for a "less code" version but it works like a charme.